# Continuity of the jet prolongation

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology, homotopy-theory, jet-bundles

I am studying the article [Immersion Theory for Homotopy theorists](https://gradmath.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/GJM2020_Weiss.pdf) by Michael Weiss for my bachelor thesis. The main theorem states that the space of immersions and formal immersions between two smooth manifolds $M$ and $N$ are weakly homotopy equivalent, with the weak equivalence given by the map
$$
\text{imm}(M,N)\to \text{fimm}(M,N),\quad f\mapsto (f,\mathrm{d}f).
$$

In the article he never mentions continuity of this map, and maybe its really trivial, but I'm having some difficulty proving this. For the first component this is almost by definition of the $C^\infty$ topology, but for the second component I can't work it out.

Could anyone help me out?

Edit: The definition I have for the weak (compact-open) $C^r$ topology is the following: For a $C^r$ map $f$ and a compact set $K$ such that $f(K)\subseteq V$ define a $\textit{weak subbasic neighbourhood}$ around  $f$ to be the set of $C^r$ maps $g: M \to N$ such that $g(K) \subseteq V$ and
$$ 
||D^k(\psi f \varphi^{-1})(x) - D^k(\psi g \varphi^{-1})(x)|| < \varepsilon,
$$
which we denote by $N^r(f, (\varphi, U), (\psi,V),K,\varepsilon)$.

Second edit: Following the comments from @ronno, here's my attempt.

For conveniency we denote the map $\text{imm}(M,N)\to \text{fimm}(M,N)$ with $\delta$. Then we inspect the pre-image of some subbasic neighborhood $N^0(df, (U,\varphi), (V,\psi), K, \varepsilon)$. As I see it, we have:
$$
\delta^{-1}(N^0(\dots))= \{g\in C^1(M,N)\mid \forall x\in \varphi(K): \quad ||D(\psi g \varphi^{-1})(x)-D(\psi f \varphi^{-1})(x)||<\varepsilon \}
$$
I suppose from here I should that every point admits a subbasic neighborhood contained in this pre-image. I'm guessing it should be something of the form $N^1(g, (\pi_M(U), ?), (\pi_N(V),?), \pi_M(K), \varepsilon/3)$ but I don't know what the charts would have to be to make this work.

Comment: Could you spell out what the *$C^\infty$ topology* is? I fail to come up with a definition in which this doesn't follow immediately.

Comment: I am using the weak $C^\infty$ topology as defined by Hirsch in his Differential Toplogy in chapter 2.1. I have interpreted the space $\text{fimm}(M,N)$  as  a subspace of the product $C^0(M,N)\times C^0(TM,TN)$.

Comment: The map is already continuous from the $C^1$ topology (by definition) and the $C^\infty$ topology is finer.

Comment: Could you maybe point out where exactly? I don't see any mention of a map $C^1(M, N)\to C^0(TM, TN)$.

Comment: This is why it's important to include the definitions (and where exactly you're having trouble applying them) in the question. If $g$ is in a $C^1$ *weak subbasic neighborhood* of $f$ then $||Df - Dg||$ is small (on a compact subset of $M$, but a compact subset of $TM$ lies over a compact set of $M$).

Comment: Thanks, I added the definition now.  I suppose you mean that the projection of a compact subset of TM is compact again with 'lies over'? Also, it is still not clear to me which open subset of M I should pick for the weak subbasic neighbourhood.

Comment: By open subset of $M$, do you mean $U$? $(\varphi, U)$ and $(\psi, V)$ are charts in $M$ and $N$ respectively and you get different subbasic neighborhoods for different choices of these. Try proving that $f \mapsto Df$ is continuous by showing that preimage of basic neighborhoods would be open even if you restricted to subbasic neighborhoods with $k = 0, 1$.

Comment: I've just edited with my attempt, could you tell me if I'm in the right direction?